# How do I write a function in C?

Tags: c, function

I'm learning C from the first section of *Objective-C Programming* by Aaron Hillegass. I'm trying to complete one of the the end-of-chapter challenges and can't seem to nail down the required function and can't find an example for guidance. I need to write a function that takes the first two angles and returns the third:

```
#include <stdio.h>

**//add your new function here**

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    float angleA = 30.0;
    float angleB = 60.0;
    float angleC = remainingAngle(angleA, angleB);
    printf("The third angle is %.2f\n", angleC);
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you are supposed to write the "remainingAngle" function.

Comment: Hi, how about you tell us, [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: The thee angles of what? Of a triangle? If that is the case then you should know that the sum of the 3 angles is 180.

Answer (score 3):

As this is a learning exercise on your part, I will not write the code for you, but will give you a few pointers.

When you compile the code you showed, it would compile fine, but would not link, complaining of missing symbol `remainingAngle` - this is the function you need to write.  In the code there is already a comment indicating where this function will go.  I'll assume that you are farmiliar (at least a little) with how functions are defined.

In your program, your function will take two arguments and return one value.  As you're dealing with angles (in a triangle?), and from existing code, you can infer that the types are `float`.  Hence you will need to add this function:

```
float remainingAngle(float angleA, float angleB) {
   ...
}
```

In place of `...` you will need to write code to compute the remaining third angle and return the value.  It can be done in several lines, e.g.

```
float angleC = ...; /* place your formula here */
return angleC;
```

or you can combine these into one line.  Now, with this info in mind, try to write the required function.  Post back if you are still encountering problems.

Comment: Got it: float remainingAngle(float angleA, float angleB) { float angleC = 180.0 - (angleA + angleB); return angleC; }

Answer (score 0):

```
float remainingAngle (float pA, float pB)
{
   return pB - pA;   // please switch to a better approach
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  ....
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to write a function is:

```
return-type function-name(list-of-arguments){
   statements
}
```

- return type :- int, double, char, float, short, long, *struct*, *pointer*
- function name :- eg. remainingAngle
- list of arguments :- comma separated eg:  float x, int y
- statements:variable declarations, statements eg. return x+y;

Comment: Got it: float remainingAngle(float angleA, float angleB)
{
float angleC = 180.0 - (angleA + angleB);
return angleC;
}